# Create a "Save As" userscript

Tags: javascript, canvas, cors, cross-domain, tampermonkey

The idea is quite simple in concept:
I would like to create a userscript that will let me press a button and save something on the page(most commonly and problematically images).
**Note: A userscript is a script that is injected client-side(by browser extensions such as Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey) and is used to add functionality to a site.**

To do so I merely need to call the `saveAs()` function and pass it the data.

The question then becomes how to I obtain the data.

Most approaches I've seen run into the situation where the resource is not of the same domain as the script perhaps?(not sure how this works).

Now, Tampermonkey(and Greasemonkey) have created a function to deal with this problem specifically - GM_XMLHTTPRequest, which can circumvent the need for proper CORS headers.

This however creates another request to the server, for a file that has already been downloaded.

My question is: **Is there a way to not have to send secondary requests to the server?**

---

Here is a chronicle of my efforts:

From what research I've managed to do, you can create a `canvas` and draw the image in there. However this "taints" the canvas, preventing it from running functions that extract that data(such as `.toBlob()` or `.toDataURL()`).
CORS offers 2 mechanisms as far as I understand it: Setting the proper HTTP headers, which requires control of the server, and a special attribute that can be put on HTML elements: `crossorigin`
I tried adding this property post-load and it won't work, you still get a tainted canvas.
Tampermonkey offers several different options on when to run the script. So the next idea was to run when the DOM is loaded, but the resources haven't yet been fetched. It seems the earliest this is possible is document-end(earlier the `getElementById` call returns `null`). However this currently returns an error when loading the image on the page(before any other additional code is run):
`Image from origin '...' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.`
There's also the `--disable-web-security` flag in Chrome, but I'd rather not go there.

Comment: So your image data is not on he same domain as your web page data? Where is your image origin in relation to your web domain?

Comment: If you just want to save a particular image as a download to something like jpg or png in the browser, I've done that.  No need to call the server again, and not sure why CORS would be an issue.  If that's the case, I can provide some tips.

Comment: @Binvention I have no idea how it works with userscripts, but all errors relate to violations of the same-origin policy. The web page is at `page.com`, and the images are at `images.page.com` @Will Yes, please. If they apply in this case, any tip would be welcome.

Comment: Yes that would interfere with cross origin because sub domains are not considered the same. For example example.com is not the same domain as image.example.com however example.com is the same as example.com/images as far as cross domain security is concerned the solution for that is adding the headers your errors are referring to your image headers before they leave the server

Comment: So you would add the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'='yourpagedomainhere' to your image headers

Comment: You do realize, I have **NO** control over the server.

Comment: The cross domain security policies were put in place to prevent the theft of things like images and the spreading of viruses so there isn't a way to get around cross domain security from just one end. If you could get around it without changing anything on the server them the security wouldn't be doing what it was suppose to.

Comment: And yet, `gm_xmlhttprequest` exists and does just that. And ironically, I was merely looking for a local-only solution to the problem.

Comment: Each of the different types of requests and responces have their own security attached too them.  The cross origin security on images is one of the more strict policies. Html on the other hand which is what xmlhttp was designed for is basic text files so it doesn't need as much security. Also the xmlhttp allows it to load but the image itself has some cross origin security thus the canvas being tainted

Comment: @martixy You can't really have *"**No** control over the server"*. If that's the case then you can't be hosting your site ... Anyway, CORS restrictions will stop other-domain exports. Without knowing I suspect your shims are first loading the cross-domain assets onto the domain server (temporarily) and  secondly delivering the now-inside-domain assets to the browser. So they are really **complying with CORS restrictions** rather than circumventing them -- at the cost of bouncing the assets off the domain server using 2 calls.

Comment: @markE It seems there is a misunderstanding over what exactly a **userscript** is. I have clarified that in the main post. It is a script injected in the page by the browser, completely client-side.

Comment: If it's completely client side then there's nothing you can do to circumvent the CORS restrictions and even if there is a way it will probably be removed in time because it is besides the point of the CORS restrictions if you could just circumvent them on the client side

Comment: Yes, there is. As already mentioned: `gm_xmlhttprequest` does exactly that. It's been there since the beginning(greasemonkey came out within half a year of firefox v1 and tampermonkey did the same once extension were introduced in chrome) and I'm 99% sure it will never be removed. Of course it also creates a superfluous request to the server. And as noted there are ways to circumvent these security features. They are purely client side, something it chooses to obey, not a server-imposed restriction. You are the client, you have complete control. As noted, Chrome has a flag that does so.

Comment: @martixy. Note that BOTH requirements must be satisfied to comply with CORS restrictions. You must set the `crossOrigin` property when making a request AND you must also configure the image hosting server to authorize & respond with the appropriate complying headers. I just took a quick look at GreaseMonkey and it seems to be a dynamic script loader (like requireJS), but I don't see where it claims to do what you desire: *"...circumvent the need for proper CORS headers"*

Comment: @markE, userscripts are more like small extensions you write for browsers, so they may have access to more powerful and less restricted features than usual javascript. According to the [greasemonkey's docs about `GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest), this method "allows these requests to cross the same origin policy boundaries.".

Comment: Also, according to these issues [(1)](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1834) [(2)](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2032), OP should be able to use `req.responseType =  'blob'` to directly pass it to the `saveAs()`. But, since the original request was made without super-privileges, he must re-request the file, so it's not marked as unsafe by the browser (for the browser, these two requests result in different files)

Comment: Your userscripts run under the grease monkey extension correct? At which point any permissions you have are as a result of what permissions you inherit from the extension. Meaning it may have additional permissions but if the browser prevents a extension from doing it it prevents your script from doing it. Even extensions have permissions even if they are elevated above website scripts which permissions it does have depends on the browser and however the grease monkey extension you're using is set up.

Comment: And as I mentioned before the type of request you're using may allow you to load the image but doing anything with the image is a different set of security features. The request allows the image to load cross origin but when you try and put it in a canvas the canvas still sees a origin that is not the same as its own so it still becomes tainted

Comment: @Binvention I didn't tested it but since GM seems to have permissions to bypass crossorigin for xhr, and that it may support blob response type, then canvas securities should be bypassed too (with the help of a FileReader) since blob are local files.  And even if it doesn't support responseType, one may be able to construct a blob from a text response.

Comment: @Kaiido they are all separate functions as far as the browser is concerned so maybe or maybe not. It's unclear and probably largely dependent on each browsers individual adaptation of CORS security on their canvas elements

Comment: @Binvention once you got the blob, the file is yours, the browser made it so it trusts it. There is no origin for blobs, they are considered as local files, no tainting on any UA I did test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it without a new request to the server.

When the first request is made, the image is marked as unsafe by the browser, and will then block a few features, like canvas' `toDataURL`, `getImageData` or `toBlob`, or in case of audio files, AudioContext's `createMediaElementSource` and `AnalyserNode`'s methods and probably some others.

There is nothing you can do to circumvent this security, once it's marked as unsafe, it is unsafe.
You then have to make a new request to the server to get a new file from the server in safe way this time.

Commonly, you would just set the `crossOrigin` attribute on the media element before doing the request, and after the server has been properly configured to answer to such requests.

Now in your case, it seems clear that you can't configure any server where your script will be used on.

But as you noticed, extensions such as GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey have access to more features than basic javascript ran from a webpage. In these features, there is one allowing your browser to be less careful about such cross-origin requests, and this is what the [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) method does.

But once again, even extensions don't have enough power to unmark non-safe media.

You must perform a new request, using their less secured way.

Comment: And it's important to note that even then it depends on what permissions the browser gives to grease monkey and what permissions grease monkey gives to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. :-) I'm not quite sure what you've discovered. Are you saying that `GM_xmlhttpRequest` can make cross-domain requests in a way that doesn't trigger tainting when drawn to canvas? If yes, can you give a simple example with an image? And if successful can you give a quick explanation of how they do it?

Comment: @markE, I didn't tested it it yet, also it's quite late here (2AM) so I may provide an example script tomorrow. But what you have to understand is that GM is a browser extension. Thus, it has access to more features. In chrome, extensions can even take a screenshot of your desktop. So it's not surprising that they can also circumvent crossorigin requests. If what the docs say about GM_xmlhttpRequest is true, then yes you can draw the image back to a canvas without tainting it since you built the image on user's side from the xhr's response. No more crossorigin involved , canvas happy.

Comment: I think I understand. So the user is implicitly allowing cross-origin requests *in advance* by installing the extension that weakens cross-origin security.

Comment: Using `canvas` is pointless in the event of making an XHR request, since the entire point of its use was to circumvent the need for making this request in the first place(i.e. keep the operation strictly local). @markE In this particular case, I am using Tampermonkey(that's the Chrome equivalent), and it does specifically trigger a prompt requesting explicit approval when you make a cross-domain request. Each script has a section "XHR Security" that handles this security consideration.

Comment: @Kaiido I am forced to make the same conclusion sadly. I alread made the script using the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` function with a `responseType: "blob",` and I cache all responses I'm interested in, so that they're available immediately when I need them. But thanks for the discussion, it's been highly informative.

Comment: @martixy. Wait ... You say, *"keep the operation strictly local"* ... is the image you want already on the user's local drive? If yes, you can use FileReader to pull it off their local drive in a CORS compliant way.

Comment: @markE I think he meant without any unnecessary call to the server.

Comment: @markE Well, given that it's been downloaded by the browser, strictly speaking, yes, it is on the local drive. In the browser's cache. Not sure if that has any relevance.